# any way to print the strings and objects, based in this function

Tags: android, json, string, apk, smali

```
public void getResponse(JSONObject jSONObject, String str) {
    RequestQueue newRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.context);
    try {
        AnonymousClass1 r1 = new JsonObjectRequest(1, str, jSONObject, new GetDataRequest$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1(this), new GetDataRequest$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0(this)) {
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
                hashMap.put(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "google-tv");
                return hashMap;
            }
        };
        r1.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20000, 1, 1.0f));
        newRequestQueue.add(r1);
    } catch (Exception unused) {
        this.listener.OnGetResponseResult((JSONObject) null, this.requestCode);
    }
}
```

m need that print values based in logcat or PrintStream.
in dont have access to source. need be inserted by smali code.

```
try inject with 
    const-string v1, "data" 
    invoke-static {v1, v11}, Landroid/util/Log;->e(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

but get error when start apk.

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class tv.google.tv
remote.GetDataRequest: void tv.google.tv.remote.GetDataRequest.getResponse(org.json.JSONObject, java.lang.S
ring) failed to verify: void tv.google.tv.remote.GetDataRequest.getResponse(org.json.JSONObject, java.lang.
tring): [0x5] cannot access instance field android.content.Context tv.google.tv.remote.GetDataRequest.conte
t from object of type Precise Reference: java.lang.String (declaration of 'tv.google.tv.remote.GetDataReque
t' appears in base.apk!classes3.dex)
```

any help please

Comment: Developing in Small is really a pain, may be you would be faster using Frida. If you don't have a rooted environment to run the app you can integrate Frida gadget library into the app and then use Frida on a connected PC to hook methods and develop JavaScript code to print out the values you want to see. In the end way faster as you don't have to rebuild the app and install it for every try, Frida allows to change the code while the app is running and JavaScript is way easier than Small.